# Java - a simple PlayerAction counter to practice object-oriented programming

Tags: java, oop, object

I am learning the basics of Java and decided to practice working on objects, by making a simple program which I called a 'PlayerAction Counter'. It does nothing more that counting an 'action' which is fired by clicking '+1' button and additionally reset the counter, when the 'Reset' button is clicked. For this case I've made a **Application.java** which holds the `main` method and launches the program, **Interface.java** for GUI, EventHandling.java for events and **Person.java** which holds interface components and methods to change their state. It looks like this:

[image]

My idea was to create the window in **Interface** class and set it's layout, then create two Person objects called PlayerOne and Player Two. The **Person** class creates two labels and two buttons and set a label of one by a constructor parameter. 
I've managed to add these two objects' elements to the GUI by *getters* and it looks just fine. I added ActionListener to both buttons in Person class and it also works just fine.

I am stuck on getting back to **Person** fields and methods from **EventHandling** class. I've created a `setValueLabel()` which increases by one a value of 'action' and sets it on the label, but I have to idea how to launch the method from another class. I can not make another object inside (throws StackOverFlow error), but should it not somehow refer to those two made in **Interface** class?

Here is the code:

**Application.java**

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                new Interface().setVisible(true);
            }   
        });
    }
}
```

**Interface.java**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSeparator;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class Interface extends JFrame {

    private JLabel titleLabel;
    private JPanel mainPanel;
    private JPanel leftPanel, rightPanel;
    private JSeparator separator;

    Person PlayerOne = new Person("PlayerOne");
    Person PlayerTwo = new Person("PlayerTwo");

    public Interface() {

        //Basic init
        setTitle("PlayerAction Counter");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        //Layout
        mainPanel = new JPanel();
        add(mainPanel);
        mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        mainPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));

        leftPanel = new JPanel();
        rightPanel = new JPanel();

        leftPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(leftPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        leftPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10,10,10,10));
        mainPanel.add(leftPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);


        separator = new JSeparator(SwingConstants.VERTICAL);
        mainPanel.add(separator, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        titleLabel = new JLabel("PlayerAction Counter");
        mainPanel.add(titleLabel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        //Components init
        PlayerTwo.getPersonLabel().setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        leftPanel.add(PlayerTwo.getPersonLabel());
        PlayerTwo.getValueLabel().setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        leftPanel.add(PlayerTwo.getValueLabel());
        PlayerTwo.getValueUpButton().setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        leftPanel.add(PlayerTwo.getValueUpButton());
        PlayerTwo.getValueResetButton().setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        leftPanel.add(PlayerTwo.getValueResetButton());

        rightPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(rightPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        rightPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10,10,10,10));
        mainPanel.add(rightPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
        PlayerOne.getPersonLabel().setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        rightPanel.add(PlayerOne.getPersonLabel());
        PlayerOne.getValueLabel().setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        rightPanel.add(PlayerOne.getValueLabel());
        PlayerOne.getValueUpButton().setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        rightPanel.add(PlayerOne.getValueUpButton());
        PlayerOne.getValueResetButton().setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        rightPanel.add(PlayerOne.getValueResetButton());
        pack();
    }
}
```

**Person.java**

```
import java.awt.Component;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Person {

    private JLabel personLabel;
    private JLabel valueLabel;
    private JButton valueUpButton;
    private JButton valueResetButton;
    private int actionValue = 0;

    public Person(String s) {

        personLabel = new JLabel(s);
        setComponents();
    }

    private void setComponents() {

        valueUpButton = new JButton("+1");
        valueResetButton = new JButton("Reset");
        valueLabel = new JLabel(""+actionValue);

        EventHandling eventHand = new EventHandling(valueUpButton, valueResetButton);
        valueResetButton.addActionListener(eventHand);
        valueUpButton.addActionListener(eventHand);
    }

    public void setValueLabel() {

        actionValue++;
        valueLabel.setText("" +actionValue);
    }


    public JLabel getPersonLabel() {

        return personLabel;
    }

    public JLabel getValueLabel() {

        return valueLabel;
    }

    public JButton getValueUpButton() {

        return valueUpButton;
    }

    public JButton getValueResetButton() {

        return valueResetButton;
    }
}
```

**EventHandling.java**

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class EventHandling implements ActionListener {

    private JButton valueUpButton;
    private JButton valueResetButton;

    public EventHandling(JButton valueUpButton, JButton valueResetButton) {

        this.valueUpButton = valueUpButton;
        this.valueResetButton = valueResetButton;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        if (event.getSource() == valueUpButton) {
            //no idea how to launch Person.setValueLabel(); 
            //creating new Person object throws StackOverFlow error and I doubt that's the way

        }

        else if (event.getSource() == valueResetButton) {

        }
    }   
}
```

I do hope my issue is understandable. The question is: how should it be done?
Please keep in mind that I am a complete rookie and try to learn OOP, but am very confused by it. Please point my mistakes in thinking and the code.
Any feedback will be greatly appraciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Pretty sure this is not good design, but you could pass the player instance (this) to the constructor of EventHandling? `new EventHandling(btnUp, btnDown, this)` Save it in a field the EventHandling class and you have access to the player from the handler.

Comment: Not strictly an answer to your question, but have you tried running through the Java trails on the Java website?

Comment: `Interface` is a very confusing class name. I recommend avoiding such names in the future (and other using other identifiers, that are similar to java keywords).